# How to interface Microcontroller with dongle device? Is it possible?

Tags: interface, microcontroller, communication, dongle

I want to interface cortex M3 microcontroller specifically [STM32F103C8T6] with a USB 3G dongle to communicate over long distance with host server/PC. But I don't know whether it is possible or not? If yes, then how?

I'm new in this field and don't know much about the microcontroller except 8051. I'm seeking help from someone experience who can give me some direction on how to get it done on this type of micro controller.

What would be the protocols or means by which we can integrate a b/w dongle device and microcontroller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its possible but it will depend of the dongle manufacturer, mi  guess is that you need to implement USB protocol on the STM32, then setup a COMM connection with the dongle and finally send AT commands to start using it

http://stm32f4-discovery.net/2015/08/hal-library-21-multi-purpose-usb-library-for-stm32fxxx/

https://www.developershome.com/sms/atCommandsIntro.asp

Comment: Thank you for your response. 
But I'm afraid i'm a total noob so I dont know how to implement or write usb protocol on STM32, if i could ask to be more specific. How would I write usb protocol on micro controller, any link or help to understand basic protocol write up would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry but an answer like that is outside of the scope of this site, you need to check the tutorials at the ST site, then check if your dongle manufacturer has public manuals or tutorials to connect with it, maybe another manufacturer manual (like sierra wireless) can help you more